# Botframework - resetting the dialogue stack not working

Tags: botframework

**What am I trying to achieve?**
I want to clear the current dialog stack from within the Controller.

**How am I trying to do this?**
When a Message activity hits the controller, the thread checks for a specific condition to tell it to clear the dialog stack.  (The flow can't use a Scorable, so has to be in the Controller)

The following code **appears** to work:

```
using (ILifetimeScope scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
{
    IBotData botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
    await botData.LoadAsync(cancellationToken);
    IDialogStack stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();
    stack.Reset();
}
```

In debug mode, before executing `stack.Reset()` you can clearly see all the dialogs in `stack.Frames` and that they're all gone after it's executed.

However...

After disposing of the scope (exiting the using block), if I then re-execute that same block  of code then the original dialogs are all there again, they've not been removed.

So...how do I remove them so that they're really gone?

Answer (score 0):

After `stack.Reset();` I just had to add `await botData.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);`.